# How to center a View inside of an Android Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to put a layout in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 160):

Step #1: Wrap whatever it is you want centered on the screen in a full-screen `RelativeLayout`.

Step #2: Give that child view (the one, which you want centered inside the `RelativeLayout`) the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` attribute.

Comment: This only worked for me when I put the attribute android:layout_centerInParent="true" into the View inside the RelativeLayout.

Comment: What if I want to position it in the center, but move it down if there's danger of overlapping with another view?

Comment: You need to put `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` on the child view, not the `RelativeLayout`. `android:layout_*` attributes affect how a view is positioned and sized within its parent, not how a view's children are positioned and sized within it.

Comment: **I'll give a BIG+1 for step 3**  .. _classic_ :-D , even though something went wrong (but don't worry about it, sure it'll b a v.silly spelling mistake).

Answer (score 31):

You can apply a centering to any View, including a Layout, by using the XML attribute android:layout_gravity".  You probably want to give it the value "center".

You can find a reference of possible values for this option here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

Comment: AFAIK, layout_gravity is only for LinearLayout, not for arbitrary layouts.

Comment: As you mentioned layout_gravity is only for LinearLayout what about RelativeLayout because because in app i want to embedd textview on ImageView

Comment: i tried it also with relativelayout and in my opinion it works

Comment: it's not only used with LinearLayout, see this example: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/

Comment: `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout` both support `android:layout_gravity` on their children. `RelativeLayout` does not. It's all [in](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html) [the](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 19):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/ProgressBar01"
        android:text="@string/please_wait_authenticating"
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:paddingTop="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 15):

I was able to center a view using

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

params.

Comment: Note that those attributes only work if the view in question is (directly) inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 9):

## Updated answer: [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

It seems that the trend in Android now is to use a Constraint layout. Although it is simple enough to center a view using a `RelativeLayout` (as other answers have shown), the `ConstraintLayout` is more powerful than the `RelativeLayout` for more complex layouts. So it is worth learning how do do now.

To center a view, just drag the handles to all four sides of the parent.

[image]

Comment: What tool do you use in order to record and create this video as a gif picture? Thank you!

Comment: @What'sUP, I can't remember which one I used for that particular animated gif. It will depend on your OS. I was using Linux. Search for something like "Linux animated gif maker" in Google. On Mac I use LICEcap now.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to center one view, use this one. In this case TextView must be the lowermost view in your XML because it's layout_height is match_parent.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_to_be_centered"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Some text"
/>
```

Comment: He meant put layout in the center, not put view.

Comment: @IgorG. positioning a layout and a View are the same because a Layout *is a* View.

Comment: the `Layout` widges do extend `ViewGroup`...But `ViewGroup` extends View. So `Layout` *is a* `ViewGroup`, and `ViewGroup` *is a* `View`

Comment: This approach will only work if the view in question doesn't have a background or an on click listener etc. - basically if you can't tell that it's being made huge. Also the view will need to support the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

It will work for that code sometimes need both properties

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add android:layout_centerInParent="true" to element which you want to center in the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2):

Use ConstraintLayout. Here is an example that will center the view according to the width and height of the parent screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You might need to change your gradle to get the latest version of ConstraintLayout:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use constraint layout. Please refer below code for the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
           android:text="Centered TextView"
       />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```