# How to Center TextViews in XML

Tags: android, xml, textview, center

How do you center TextViews in xml?

Example:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_3"
    android:text="@string/text_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we put layout in center of the screen in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499258/can-we-put-layout-in-center-of-the-screen-in-android)

Comment: You want to center TextView in its parent layout or center displayed text in the TextView?

Comment: If you searched or google it you will easily get the answer, -1 for your effort...

Comment: It was designed to be a helpful index for other people to google.  I answered it.  This is a "q and a" style question.  I know the answer and was only trying to help people who don't.

Comment: Center displayed text in the TextView.

Comment: @epicness_studios The titles make it seem like it is not a dupe, but the subject matter is the same. The ways you center a layout are the same as the ways you center any View including TextView. Between the 4 answers given in that question they cover everything that was posted as an answer here...Note that I see nothing wrong with you posting it, vote to close is not personal. And even with the question "closed" it will remain online for others to find in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center text horizontally and vertical in a TextView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

> android:gravity="center"

in your Layout and Textview . Look this Exam.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `layout_gravity` to the TextView

try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_3"
    android:text="@string/text_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center text in xml using,

```
android:gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Setting the gravity to center will center the text in the TextView, whereas centering the TextView vertically and horizontally will do just that.